# php setcookie specific expire date not working

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie with a specific expiry date using ....

```
$result=setcookie("testA", "A", strtotime("2038-01-01 23:59:59"));
```

but this is returning [$result=] true, but the expiry date is 2023-12-08.

To test this further I've run the following PHP, and find that the dates become static after test14.

```
$chk=2147483647;
$monthNb = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;

for($n=0; $n<40; $n++) {

   $nn=$n;
   if ( $n<10 ) $nn="0$nn";

   $v=$n*$monthNb;
   if ( $v>$chk ) echo "<LI>ERR $v";
   setcookie("test$nn", "$v", time() + $v);
}
```

Resulting in...
[image]

How do I get the expiry date to simply run on a specific date?

Comment: Your code is working fine on my local server, expire dates keep going up a month until the end. Maybe a limitation of the server itself ? (it is possible to set cookie expiration dates in Apache configuration for example)

Comment: I have the same problem right now. If I set cookie with expire big enough, it really creates with expire about 1 year 1 month and 3 days from now, just like on the picture above. But this occurs only on Chrome, on FF expire is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[There was a change](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4887741241229312) in Chrome 104 which sets max expire time to be no more than 400 days.

As I can see from your picture, your browser sets cookie for exactly 400 days.

*From there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73557227/1378713*

Answer (score 0):

```
$expiration_date = strtotime("+1 year");
$result = setcookie("testA", "A", $expiration_date);
```

In this example, strtotime("+1 year") calculates the current date and time plus one year. You can adjust the string passed to strtotime as necessary to meet specific cookie expiry requirements.

Hope this helps.